# SPoodle Scheduling cannot work in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin

I add a free application **SPoodle Scheduling** to my site SharePoint 2013. (SharePoint Enterprise) But when I try to open this **SPoodle Scheduling** app, there always a error message.
[image]

How could I use this application ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in [Configure an environment for apps for SharePoint (SharePoint 2013)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161236.aspx) your DNS should be set up to have a wildcard CNAME for *.ContosoApps.com, where ContosoApps.com is the domain configured for apps (which hopefully match the obfuscated part of your image).